# Fitnesse Scenario library local to Suite level not oncluded

Tags: fitnesse, scenarios, fitnesse-slim

I have my test cases in Fitnesse suite. I have created a Scenario Library local to the suite. But inside the test page its not getting loaded.

here is my Structure

- My Tests

  - Contents

    - Test1
    - Test2
    - Suite1

      - ScenarioLibrary
      - Test1

So under Test1, I cannot see the contents of the Scenario Library. here is the screen shot of what I see,

[image]

As you can see, its picking up my library name but its just displayed as plain text not with and Include Page and expand option.

Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and in that case one of my parent page names was not a valid 'wiki word'. When I renamed that page all went well.

Any chance `Step02IPhoneSuite` causes a similar problem? I don't recall the definition of wiki word of the top of my head, but I notice 2 capitals next to each other in that name. If you rename that page to `Step02iPhone`, does that help?